# Check if Date is 2 months prior to today's date

Tags: vba, excel, date, dateadd

I want to check if a variable date is in the month that is two months prior to today's date.

Is there a way (using a built in date funciton like dateadd()) to cover the edge cases of when `month(now())=1 or month(now())=2` in more elegant manner than the following?

```
?format(month(now()) & " " & year(now()),"MMMM YYYY")=format(dateadd("M",2,format(varMonth & " " & varYear, "MMMM YYYY")),"MMMM YYYY")
```

Comment: [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/datediff-function)?

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!

Comment: @Vincent G please share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. | Alternatively, the question owner (forestaker) may do so too.. (:

Comment: @p._phidot_ Well, it was more an hint than a answer. Done.

Comment: IMHO, a good hint is much better than direct answers. [ : Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/datediff-function) function with the "m" interval to calculate the difference in months between two dates.